# Index-Match with Vertical & Horizontal criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am certain that the below index match with multiple criteria should work but for some reason it isn't. A few things about the data in B1:H1 and K1, they are dynamic values, that is, they aren't "dates" so to speak. B1 has a value of `=TODAY()+2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())` and K1 has a value of `=TODAY()`.

I can't convert it to a table as I need the headers to be dynamic.

[image: Data Grid]

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a vlookup + a match works. If you guys figure out why the index match works on atable and let me know that would be great!

```
=VLOOKUP(K2, $A$1:$H$15, MATCH($K$1, $A$1:$H$1,0), FALSE)
```

Comment: Guys, the reason index match wasn't working on the dynamic variable data is because I was using an old version of excel. I tried it again with excel 2018 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try one match to column A and another completely separate match to row 1. In other words, one match for the row number and another for the column number.,

```
=index(a$1:h$15, match(k2, a:a, 0), match(k$1, $1:$1, 0))
```

Fill down for the other row-by-column matches.

Comment: It didn't work. Not sure why I think combining Vertical & horizontal has something to do with it.

Comment: tbh, it doesn't. I did notice that I started that formula with a hyphen instead of 
 an equals and I should have locked 1:1 as absolute (e.g. $1:$1) but those minor errors would have presented themselves quickly. Frankly, I'm not sure  what *'It did't work'* means either. :)

Comment: By "it doesn't work" I mean it returns 43263 (the numerical version of the date for 06/12/18). I have a rough idea why that is but I could be wrong. I believe the second match in that string is acting as a column locator. That is the second column.

The typos were not the issue I can fix those with no problem. if I get it to work for the first one I can sufficiently get it to work for the rest.